# Trying to pass gulp environment-dependent web-pack variables into angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, webpack

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and gulp and webpack so excuse me if I'm not using correct terminologies. Been reading stack overflow and angularjs stuff for 2 hours and can't make the connections with what I'm reading.

I'm coming into an already developed application and trying to find the best way to include analytics API keys from a webpack plugin variables into the AngularJS app to use.

The directory is setup as such:

```
ng_organize
    /gulp
        /tasks
            webpack-development.js
            webpack-production.js
        /util
    /src
        /appName
            /customer
                CustomerController.js
                ...
            /home
            /shop
        app.js
        index.js
    application.js
```

The webpack variables in `ng_organize/gulp/tasks/webpack-development.js` are:

```
gulp.task('webpack:development', function(callback){
    webpack({
        context: ...
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin {
                GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY: 'XXX',
                ...
            }    
        ]
    });
});
```

Currently, the webpack variables can be accessed in `ng_organize/application.js` with `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY`. I'm trying to access them within `ng_organize/src/appName/customer/CustomerController.js`.

I want to create a service to store GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY (and other keys) that is dependent on the environment. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out they are automatically included globally in your app's code, you just won't be able to call the global variables in the debugger (which was how I was testing to see if they were accessible inside the CustomerController).

`GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY` is still accessible inside CustomerController.